# error when I throw a HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to return a status code saying that the user is not found when the user doesn't exist in the database

```
[Route("api/users/user")]
public User GetUser(String username)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    user result = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(u=>u.username == username).FirstOrDefault();

    //If the user doesn't exist
    if (result == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    User user = new User();

    //Initialize the user
    user.user_id = result.user_id;
    user.username = result.username;
    user.password = result.password;
    user.email = result.email;

    return user;

   }
```

but I get this error:

> Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see
>   the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this
>   exception for details.

[image]

Here's the response I send

```
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Could not find username: ImNotaRealUser', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
}}
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you

**EDIT**

It only happens on my laptop. Is it a problem with IIS?

Comment: What was the exception returned by the service?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand but I think this is the exception. I added a screenshot.

Comment: What is this code that we see on the screenshot? It is not the code you quote.

Comment: It's a generic method to handle the exceptions. I do have the same error with the code I posted.